# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter динамическая разметка

Tags: android, firebase, recyclerview.adapter

Ребят,вопрос в следующем. Можно ли как-то динамически менять свойства разметки?поясню: Имеется переписка между 2-мя пользователями,и есть 1 разметка для самих сообщений.
вот метод инициализации и настройки адаптера:

```
 mFBAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, FirechatMsgViewHolder>(
            ChatMessage.class,
           // chat_message собственно сама разметка текстового сообщения
            R.layout.chat_message,
            FirechatMsgViewHolder.class,
            mDatabaseReference.child(romName)
    ) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(FirechatMsgViewHolder firechatMsgViewHolder, ChatMessage chatMessage, int i) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

            firechatMsgViewHolder.msgText.setText(chatMessage.getText())          firechatMsgViewHolder.userText.setText(chatMessage.getName());


            if (mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() == null) {
                firechatMsgViewHolder.userImage.setImageDrawable(
                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_36dp));
            } else {
                mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
                mPhotoUrl = mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
                Glide.with(ChatFragment.this).
                        load(chatMessage.getPhotoUrl()).into(firechatMsgViewHolder.userImage);
            }
        }
    };

    mFBAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
            int chatMsgCount = mFBAdapter.getItemCount();
            int lastVisiblePosition = mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                    (positionStart >= (chatMsgCount - 1) && lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                mMsgRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
            }
        }
    });

    mMsgRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mMsgRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFBAdapter);

    mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName().toString();
```

у меня есть имена обоих учасников,и я хотел как то с их помощью сделать так,что бы сообщения отправленные пользователем отображались у него справа,а принятые - слева. Есть константы Gravity.LEFT и Gravity.RIGHT,с помощью которых можно управлять положение из кода,но как это прикрутить.
был вариант типа

```
 if(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName().equals(mUsername)){
        // gravity right...

    } else {
        // gravity lef.....
    }
```

но это не сработало.Есть какие-то мысли,может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете сделать вот так:

```
 adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MessageModel, ChatMessageHolder>(MessageModel.class, R.layout.item_message_once,
                ChatMessageHolder.class, query) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ChatMessageHolder viewHolder, MessageModel model,
                                              int position) {

                //which will align?
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvTime_params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                        viewHolder.tvTime.getLayoutParams();
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams llContent_params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                        viewHolder.llContent.getLayoutParams();

                //align all in the right
                if (myUid != null && myUid.equals(model.author_uid)) {
                    tvTime_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, R.id.llContent);
                    llContent_params.setMargins(px140, 0, 0, 0);
                    viewHolder.llContent.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
                } else {
                    //align all in the left
                    tvTime_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, R.id.llContent);
                    llContent_params.setMargins(0, 0, px140, 0);
                    viewHolder.llContent.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border_white_gray));
                }
                //set params for align
                viewHolder.tvTime.setLayoutParams(tvTime_params);
                viewHolder.llContent.setLayoutParams(llContent_params);

                //set values for fields
                String timestamp = sdf.format(new Date(model.message_time));
                viewHolder.tvTime.setText(timestamp);
                viewHolder.tvBody.setText(model.message_body);
            }
        };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter );
```

Этот код проверяет uId автора сообщения, и если он ваш, то item будет сделан справа, а если другого пользователя, то слева + добавляем бэкграунд и другие параметры, при необходимости.